# Upgrade scenarios for Ubuntu 14.04 system running old VirtualBox: Is there a preferred path?

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, virtualbox

I am planning some overdue upgrades for an Ubuntu 14.04 box I built two years ago, hosting some VM's under VirtualBox version 4.3.22. As I'm planning to upgrade both the OS (to 16.04.1) and VBox (to latest 5.x version), it seems I have two options, and I'm going in circles arguing with myself which path is better/smarter:

- Perform the OS kernel upgrade *first*, THEN upgrade VirtualBox
- Perform the VitrualBox upgrade, THEN the OS kernel upgrade

The network configuration on my box is a little unusual, and that leads me to do the OS first, but I'm going to have to update that no matter which I do first. I thought I'd solicit some feedback from the more learned here :)

Comment: Vbox in the Ubuntu 14.04 repos is 4.3.36 - you're already *downgraded* from 14.04. Uninstall that non-Ubuntu version of Vbox, do-release-upgrade your entire system to 16.04, and try your vdis on the Ubuntu version of Vbox (5.0.32).   Since you have customized your system and are using non-Ubuntu software, backup all your data and vdis before starting - customization sometimes leads to  breakage.

Comment: Hmmm...not quite sure how I managed to get a non-Ubuntu release - was not intentional. Anyway, circumstances more or less compelled me to move forward with this today and I opted to upgrade VBox only and added to my trusted sources. Aside from some dummy-on-me issues that delayed things (that had nothing to do with Ubuntu or Vbox), the upgrade went flawlessly and I am up and running. Already enjoying the newer VBox features (especially detachable headless consoles!) Thx